# Pie chart labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been unable to get labels to appear correctly around my pie chart - regardless of which direction I choose to construct it and after much fiddling with variables, the labels go in the opposite direction of my slices (clockwise when the graph constructs counterclockwise and vice versa).

```
> piedata
Source: local data frame [15 x 4]
Groups: Array [3]
     Array     variable value position
    <fctr>       <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>
1  Array 1        Empty 13.28    6.640
2  Array 1 FAM-Negative 34.28   30.420
3  Array 1           WT  6.45   50.785
4  Array 1          MUT  2.64   55.330
5  Array 1          HET 43.16   78.230
6  Array 2        Empty 19.63    9.815
7  Array 2 FAM-Negative 45.31   42.285
8  Array 2           WT  4.49   67.185
9  Array 2          MUT  1.37   70.115
10 Array 2          HET 28.81   85.205
11 Array 3        Empty  2.64    1.320
12 Array 3 FAM-Negative 52.34   28.810
13 Array 3           WT  4.39   57.175
14 Array 3          MUT  0.98   59.860
15 Array 3          HET 39.26   79.980

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

pieplot <- ggplot(piedata, aes(x = factor(1), y = value, fill = variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) + 
    coord_polar(theta = "y", direction = -1) + 
    geom_text_repel(aes(x = 1.4, y = piedata$position, label = piedata$value), size = 3) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = plotcolors[4:8]) + 
    facet_grid(.~Array, labeller = label_value) + 
    labs(fill = "Array Yield") +
    theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
          axis.text = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          panel.spacing = unit(8.25, "lines"), 
          legend.position = "left")
```

This is as far as I've gotten, and it yields something like this:

[image: plot].

Edit:  Position comes from the following, which I saw in several other threads as the best formatting calculation

```
piedata <- piedata %>% group_by(Array) %>% mutate(position = cumsum(value) - value/2)
```

Comment: Look at it without `coord_polar`; whatever `position` is supposed to be, it's the wrong numbers. Also, the fact that you need labels is an indicator that this is a bad way to display your data.

Comment: That made it a lot more intuitive, thanks!  And I absolutely agree on the latter :/

    position = 100-cumsum(value)+value/2